# How to cancel the animation of $state.go()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

$state.go() is the method of page-redirecting.But the result is not satisfactory.So how can I cancel this animation

Comment: What is not satisfactory?  What is the animation?  Post the relevant code an a little more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following to disable the state transition animation:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
     disableAnimate: true
});
```

... and here is a little more documentation on $ionicHistory:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/